# What is the guideline for citing code from outside of the Stack Exchange network?

Tags: discussion, attribution

I needed a good way to validate a password check through angelorjs. I wasn't completely satisfied with the answers of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14012239/password-check-directive-in-angularjs/18997012) since it didn't explain the problem very well.

Later I found [this blog post](http://piotrbuda.eu/2013/02/angularjs-directive-for-password-matching.html) that was a good read about it. I [adding it up in an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14012239/password-check-directive-in-angularjs/18997012#18997012) in case other people were having the same issue. I referenced to the blog post and mentioned his name as well.

Since I always hate it when there's an possibly good answer with a broken link I added the solution on his blog post as well. In the end I mentioned the credit goes to the author. Is this good practice or should I remove it?

Comment: That is perfect.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really "good answers"?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: @hjpotter92 Not really a duplicate of that - this is the inverse situation! - but that topic is certainly very relevant here.

Comment: @hjpotter92 i indeed saw that one but since it was about putting a link without code and nothing about citing guidelines i didn't thought it to be applicable to this situation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is perfectly good practice. You did everything right:

- You provided actual useful code in your answer.
- Not being the original author, you cited the code source.
- You did not simply link to code elsewhere that, as you say, could have just become a broken link.
- Hopefully, the code you provided also works and is useful to others trying to find out about this. I trust that's the case here.
- You came here to share your knowledge on an issue to benefit others in the future!

Comment: thanks for the reassurance :) I wasn't really sure of it.